# How do I rerun the second-to-last command?

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-history

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10. If I mess up, I can re-run the last command with `!!`. Here's an example:

```
$ apt update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
$ sudo !!
sudo apt update
[sudo] password for [me]:
...
Fetched 336 kB in 2s (206 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
98 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

That's fine, but instead of rerunning the previous command, how can I run the one before it? Like this:

```
$ echo hi
hi
$ echo hello
hello
$ !!   <-- I'm trying to get that to run 'echo hi'
hello
```

Basically, here's what I'm looking for

```
$ echo hi
hi
$ echo hello
hello
$ ???   <-- What can I put here to get it to run 'echo hi'?
echo hello!
hello!
```

So, given that `!!` runs the last command, how can I run the command before the previous one? In my example, instead of typing `!!`, what can I run to execute `echo hi`?

Comment: The shortcuts like `!!` were useful in plain old `sh`, where there was no command history and editing. In `bash`, there's no more need to use them as you can freely go to previous/next commands by pressing up/down arrow.

Comment: `echo $(!-2)`, there's also a possibility to embed event designators.

Comment: If you want to run the command before you ran the previous one, I'd suggest using a time machine add-on to bash. Whereas, if you want to re-run the command before last, that's a different story.

Comment: Yes... "re-run the command before last" or "re-run Nth command from history"

Comment: @raj In agreement with bac0n, I also use them for embedding. Sometimes I run one command, then another, then I want to compare the outputs, and do something like `diff -u <(!-2) <(!!)` or `comm -23 <(!-2 | sort) <(!! | sort)`. Another common use of history expansion for me is `!$` to reuse the last argument of the previous command in a new one, like `aur fetch foo` to make a build directory for an AUR package foo, then `cd !$` to change the working directory to it.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html, Ctrl-F "Commands for Manipulating the History"

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From the `HISTORY EXPANSION` section of `man bash`:

```
!-n    Refer to the current command minus n
```

So to run the command before last, you can use `!-2`

In fact, `!!` is just a synonym of `!-1`

Comment: You mean computer scientists start counting from zero when going forward, but from -1 when going backwards?  Where did these nerds learn to count?

Comment: @MikeMaxwell must just be a quirk of history :-D

Comment: @MikeMaxwell, in this case, 0 is what you're currently entering; -1 is the previous command, -2 is the previous but one. It makes sense to me :-)

Comment: @OmarL So, if the next command I'm going to type is going to be `echo "The stock market is going to be X"` in two hours, does that mean I can use `!1` to see what the stock market is going to be two hours from now?

Comment: @HiddenWindshield That's ... creative, but no dice: `-bash: !1: event not found`

Answer (score 41):

You can use the <kbd>up-arrow</kbd> and <kbd>down-arrow</kbd> keys to cycle through your command history. So to re-run the second-last command, you'd press <kbd>up-arrow</kbd> twice, then <kbd>return</kbd>.

This has several advantages over methods like `!-2`. Most importantly (in my opinion), you can see the command and make sure it's the one you intended to re-run before pressing return to execute it. Even aside from simple mistakes ("oops, I guess it was the third command back that I wanted"), bash history may not count previous commands the way you expect because of options like `ignorespace`, `ignoredups`, and the `HISTCONTROL` variable.

Also, interactive command recall lets you easily edit the command before re-running it. You can do that with history recall modifiers as well, but again doing it interactively lets you see your edits before executing the recalled/modified command.

Plus if you're lazy like me, <kbd>up-arrow</kbd> <kbd>up-arrow</kbd> <kbd>return</kbd> is easier to type than <kbd>(shift)exclamation</kbd> <kbd>minus</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>return</kbd>

Comment: "Most importantly (in my opinion), you can see the command and make sure it's the one you intended to re-run before pressing return to execute it." If you enable `histverify` then any command with history substitution will need to be confirmed before parsed by the shell.
However, I am lazy like you so I would favor your suggestion in this particular case.

Comment: If you prefer to retain your hands around the home row, rather than wandering over the keyboard, an easier combo would be Ctrl-P (memorize as "Previous") instead of the UpArrow, and Ctrl-N (as for "Next") instead of the DownArrow. Thus, Ctrl-PP, Return.

Comment: With a major downside being a lack of scriptability. At least in any sensible form.

Comment: You can also press M-^ (i.e. Alt+Shift+6 or ESC Shift+6) to initiate history expansion on the current line.

Answer (score 7):

`!-n` execute command "-n" of your history, but I wouldn't recommend it, as it is "instant" and will not give you time to check first that the "Nth" command is the right one you need to execute again... ( @bac0n nicely remarked that you can set : `shopt -s histverify` to switch it to "non instant": it will let you verify the command !-n expands to, before executing it with `<Enter>`)

However, if you are using `bash` as your shell, I much prefer to recommend using the search feature:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  and then type `something`, which is the part of the command that you are looking for. (ex: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> + (type into terminal) `echo`)

It will present the latest occurrence in your history matching `something` (i.e., matching the search term that you typed after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>).

Subsequent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> will look further back in your history. Or adding letters will precise the search.

And once you find a good match, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute it again (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to exit from the search without executing the currently displayed matching command).

Additional tip: if, instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> , you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> , it will execute the selected history command AND present the next one, ready to be executed with <kbd>Enter</kbd> (which only execute that one and returns to the normal prompt) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> again (which executes it and present the next command in your history). Very useful to repeat a sequence of steps, and providing a display of those commands before executing them.

And each time you use those things, you are allowed to change something on the currently displayed line (using the left or right arrow key to move within it), such as a parameter, a server name, etc., and execute that modified line + go to the next one (if you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>).

Comment: It's depended on how you set up the shell option... you can append `shopt -s histverify` if you don't want to run the entry directly.

Comment: Also, you might add that this is bash specific. Most modern shells have history tracking / rerun in one form or another, but the implementation and syntax / shortcuts will be different from one shell to the next.

Comment: thanks @NateT and bac0n , 2 good points I omitted in my answer. I edited it in.

Comment: To complement Ctrl-R for `reverse-i-search`, there's Ctrl-S for forward `i-search` (useful when you missed the right entry and need to go "back"), though there's [a caveat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/791765/673852).

Comment: @Ruslan adds an interresting thing, but I didn't bother to add that one as it is less often used and it is sometimes linked to other things (ctrl-s [stops the terminal from outputting characters] ctrl-q [resumes the character output], for exemple, by default in lots of shells. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72092/27616 ). Some additionnal setting (of readline? and stty) may be required to set it all working, and exemples can be found on unix.se

Comment: @OlivierDulac that's exactly the caveat that my link addresses :)

Comment: @Ruslan : oops, didn't notice that one, sorry ^^

Answer (score 5):

If you run

```
history
```

you'll get a list of the last 'n' commands entered. The history size defaults to 500 commands. So, as explained by steeldriver, the command before last one can be rerun with

```
!-2
```

and yes, the third to last will be

```
!-3
```

and so on. For more details, use

```
man history
```

and search for **Event Designators**.

Comment: A small addition: you can run a specific command from the history by just using `!312` (to run the command with the line number 312 shown in your history output). Even more useful tip: If you had a typo in that command, you can run `!312:p` which will not execute the command but still put it on top as "last used command". This helps you in editing longer commands without manual copy-paste from the history by simply using arrow up and editing the command before running it.

Comment: Great! The list of modifiers of "history" is full of surprises. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On top of using <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> `<term>` or `!-2` to re-run an old command, you can also view your command history and run it by index as well. Say your history looks like:

```
  ...
  1770  ls         
  1771  git status 
  1772  git add .  
  ...
```

You can run `!1772` to re-run the 1772'th `git add .`.

My workflow is sometimes `history |`[`bat`](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) then <kbd>/</kbd>`<term>` and running the specific entry from there.